# Привязка стороннего значения к checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

Подскажите как привязать вводимое значение пользователем к чекбоксу? Пользователь выбирает чекбоксами сайты и вводит в поле инпут какое то значение потом отправляет форму как привязать и поймать каждое значение к каждому сайту для дальнейшей записи в БД. Значение в велью передается вместе с чекбоксом а вот привязать сторонний инпут что то не выходит никак. Код:

```
<div id="panel" class="multiselect"></br>
    <?php $rr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phones");
    while ($ww = mysql_fetch_array($rr)) { ?>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="<?= $ww['id'] ?>"
                value=""/><?php echo $ww['phone'] . "->" . $ww['comments'] ?> </label>
        <input type="text" id="taxes" size="20" placeholder="цена заявки\звонка"></br></br>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="taxes[<?= $ww['id'] ?>]"
    size="20" placeholder="цена заявки\звонка">
```

И Вам придет массив `taxes` с ключами идентификаторами сайтов